# A service to run a single lengthy computation

Tags: python, computation

This is for testing some heavy operation that my computer will take about a month to run and I need the results in a few days.

This is basically a one-time test (or maybe a few times) so I don't want to go into renting computational power etc., only to run it, get the results, and pay for how much it costs.

I'm imagining a box where I paste my code (Python), pay a few bucks and run it.

Is there any service that provides this kind of functionality?

Comment: Computational power costs money whichever way you look at it. Today, services allow for on-demand payment. Set your desired CPU speed and pay just for the time you use. No way around it.

Comment: This actually sounds good, which services provide this?

Comment: Most of the mainstream services - Google Cloud, Amazon AWS, Oracle Cloud, Vultr... All of them even have a free trial (limited credit).

Comment: Thanks so this is done through a "virtual machine"? that's basically what I was not sure of

Comment: Yes, usually it is a virtual machine, the provider creates it with the desired limits on their bare metal and provides you with SSH access, so you can upload your Python script and run it. Create some kind of notification (email I guess)  so you know it's done and you can turn it off. You usually pay by the hour, but there are other models.

Comment: Also, watch out -- for AWS it is not enough to stop your instance, you also have to terminate it. Stopping is shutting down, terminating is you saying "I won't start it up again, release the resources". It cost me a few bucks before I realized that